# Speeding up an inefficient filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a parameterized stored procedure. One of the parameters is `@aName` which is allowed to be `NULL` and often is null.

The query within the stored procedure contains the following filter:

```
AND Name LIKE ('%' + ISNULL(@aName,Name) + '%')
```

This filter works but strikes me as inefficient for the following reason:

If `@aName` is null then we just want `Name = Name` but we are getting `Name LIKE ('%Name%')`.

How do I short-circuit the filter so that I get the following:

1. If @aName is null then use `Name = Name` or `1=1`.
2. If @aName is not null then use `Name LIKE ('%Name%')`.

Comment: You can add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to get it to take account of the actual variable value though you'd probably still need to write it as `AND (@aName IS NULL OR Name LIKE ('%' + @aName + '%') )`

Comment: @MartinSmith added. Do I need to flush out old retained plans or should adding the hint suffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query that you are thinking of is:

```
AND (@aName IS NULL OR Name LIKE ('%' + @aName + '%') )
```

I don't think there will be a major speed difference.

You could also "unwrap" the whole query:

```
IF (@aName IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT . . .
    FROM . . .
    WHERE . . .
END;
ELSE
    SELECT . . .
    FROM
    WHERE . . . AND
          LIKE ('%' + @aName + '%') 
END;
```

This would have an optimization advantage for the first version.

Comment: I've unwrapped to a point - in the script we have three conditions like this - so unwrapping fully would mean lots of possible IF statements covering the different permutations.

Comment: Due to SQL Server performing parameter sniffing, the DB tends to optimize based on whatever parameter is passed into the procedure the first time.  Which means the _second_ time you run it might have a big difference (ie, counting population of Rhode Island vs. Texas...)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse will the hint `WITH RECOMPILE` possibly help? If it does not help what should I do?

Comment: @whytheq . . . The hint `with recompile` should help.

Comment: @whytheq - Your db may not be large enough to matter.  Otherwise, you have to "force" the recompile somehow, either by the query hint, or using dynamic SQL (which would eliminate the need for this sort of trick, by essentially always presenting a new statement).  I don't know if 2012 "fixed" this (DB2 does by caching something like the last 100 plans, and not retaining the first one indefinitely either).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse hmmm - I've added the hint - do I need to get rid of the old retained plan?

Comment: I doubt it.  Either it's ignored, or will be reused if the parameter matches (maybe?).  Compared to the amount of data selected, plans are usually pretty small in size.

Answer (score 3):

Only check if the name is like `@aName` when `@aName` is not `null`.

```
AND (@aName is null or Name LIKE '%' + @aName + '%')
```